# SoapHttpClientProtocol, does the method invoke open a new connection everytime?

Tags: c#, .net

I have imported the wsdl. I got the class with web service's methods. The class
derives from SoapHttpClientProtocol.

Could anyone tell me if every method invocation opens a new connection or maybe the connection is reused?

If it is not reused how can be reused?

And the last question, Can I Make a client to be a WCF one? And How to import wsdl
for the wcf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it a WCF service, you'll have to create an interface instead of simply decorating the methods. To import it into your project, it works the same way.

I'm not sure about 2.0 services, but with WCF, it depends on how you invoke the service client. As far as I know, in general, the connection stays open until you close it, or until it loses scope (inconsistently). So once it's a WCF service, instantiate the client, make all of your calls, then close it. I guess the best practice right now is to wrap it in a try/catch and have the catch block .abort the client. It has been my experience though, that if your service is loosely coupled, and you're not trying to pipe a huge amount of data, then the repeated connections aren't a huge deal.

A side thought though: if your service is doing something like opening a SQL connection, then keep that in mind that the sql connection will be made with every service call regardless of the client's connection state. This is one of those dirty situations where you might want to whore the sql connection around the inside of the service to complete your operations and return a dataset or some form of DTO to save yourself the tennis match between client and service.